# Seting up WiFi Usb dongle

Tags: raspbian, usb, peripherals

I have got an AirStream TM 1100 WiMAX USB Adapter. It works without any drivers on a PC using Ubuntu but will not work on my Raspberry Pi. The [kztech.cn](http://www.kztech.cn/en/AirStream1100.asp) website does not provide any drivers for the device. Could anybody help me install it?

Comment: Could you put the contents of `dmesg`, `lsusb`, and `lsmod` run on Ubuntu with the adapter plugged in on http://pastebin.com?

Comment: In ubuntu, [`dmesg`](http://pastebin.com/ieaEx6Sd), [`lsusb`](http://pastebin.com/ghvdN5py) and [`lsmod`](http://pastebin.com/37EENkxd). Sorry that I was gone. I am back again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insufficient RPi and USB power supply?

The normal RPi PSU and USB port might not have enough power/current for a USB modem. Maybe try it through a powered USB hub or at least a higher current RPi PSU. I have a Nexus 7 PSU that is 2A it sorted a few problems out.

Comment: Nope. Not that. I know that my USB dongle is receiving power properly.

Comment: Are you running it through a powered USB hub? The USB ports only have about 100mA current - not the same as a USB on your PC.

Comment: sorry, I tried a hub and it worked :D